# How to access Google Cloud Datastore entity with dash in its name?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a Google App Engine project and I need to access a Datastore entity with a name that contains dash, e.g. `random-entity`. I want to do that in Python. Since `random-entity` is invalid syntax for a class name, I cannot create a model and access it like that.

So how can I access this entity? Is it possible to do that without creating a model and just retrieve it in JSON format?

Keep in mind that renaming the entity is not an option for the project I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [**NDB** library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) you need to override [class method `_get_kind(cls)`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/model.py#L3044) of model, like this:

```
class RandomEntity(ndb.Model):

  @classmethod
  def _get_kind(cls):
    return 'random-entity'

  # You can override property name as well
  random_name = ndb.StringProperty('random-name')
```

EDIT: Added missing colon after _get_kind

Comment: I guess this pretty much answers my question, but I still cannot get it to work. I want to retrieve the entity by using its key. I have something like `key = Key('random-entity', '<key-value>')`, but whenever I try to call `key.get()` I get `KindError: No model class found for kind 'random-entity'. Did you forget to import it?`. The `RandomEntity` class is in the same file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually I gave you wrong answer. The proper line in sources is https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/model.py#L3044 - so you need to overrider the `@classmethod def _get_kind(cls)` - I will updated the answer. Sorry for misleading!

Comment: Key(RandomEntity, '<key-value>') should work, it will use it's internal kind name by itself.